# Copying files from a dynamic folder structure [Windows]

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy

I'm trying to create a scheduled task that will run every morning to copy a file from a folder to another. So here's the problem,

The source folder's name is dynamic and starts off with the daily date (i.e. "06-Feb-13").
How can I go about creating a batch file which will be able to determine the daily date and find that folder?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/203116/1064610)

Comment: Thanks @ACB, that was basically what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a%%b)
echo %mydate%_%mytime%
```

This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/203116/1064610) will help you.

Comment: To add to this answer, see the "Map and Lookup" section on this [DOS String Manipulation](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) page to see how to convert the 2-digit month to its alpha abbreviation.

Comment: @rojo Thanks for the followup help!

Comment: You can vote up comments as well as answers to increase its value

Answer (score 0):

If it's the newest folder you're looking for, then you can do a directory listing sorted by creation date and act on the last entry.  If you know the directory you need will always be the most recently created, then there's no need to scrape and compare the actual date.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f %%I in ('dir /t:c /o:d /b "c:\path\to\containing\dir\*."') do set dir=%%I
copy "%dir%\*.*" "c:\destination\folder"
```

Note that I'm doing `dir "path\*."` and not `dir "path\*.*"`.  The `*.` will match directories but not files.

Comment: It's not the newest folder. All the folders are created at the same time but just named to the date.

Comment: @JeffreyTong - in that case, [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)?

Comment: I was searching for a something to display the current date so I can truncate it to the proper format and use that as the directory name.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final solution I came up with for the date:

```
@echo off

REM -- Convert number to 3 character month--

set v=%date:~4,2%
SET map=01-Jan;02-Feb;03-Mar;04-Apr;05-May;06-Jun;07-Jul;08-Aug;09-Sep;10-Oct;11-Nov;12-Dec
CALL SET v=%%map:*%v%-=%%
SET v=%v:;=&rem.%

set y=%date:~12,4%
set d=%date:~7,2%

set "mydate=%d%-%v%-%y%"

echo %mydate%
```